# how to make the first column of id always equal to the value of the row? even after adding and deleting rows

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

how to edit an sql table using sqlite3 to create a column with values corresponding to the row number.
I have a list

```
 ['7' '19' '11' '11' 'Комплекс 1300 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['8' '191' 'nn' '11' 'Комплекс 1300 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['10' '19' 'ss' '11' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['11' '19' 'ss' '1' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['12' '191' 'mm' '11' 'Комплекс 1300 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['13' '19' 'ss' '11' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['14' '19 'ss' '1' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
```

The first column name is 'id'
I want the id column to always match the row number, even after deleting or adding a new row to the table

this sql command doesn't work for some reason

```
   cursor.execute("UPDATE mytable SET id = rowid")
```

how to make the first column of id always equal to the value of the row? even after adding and deleting rows

I want it to look like this

```
 ['1' '19' '11' '11' 'Комплекс 1300 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['2' '191' 'nn' '11' 'Комплекс 1300 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['3' '19' 'ss' '11' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['4' '19' 'ss' '1' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['5' '191' 'mm' '11' 'Комплекс 1300 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['6' '19' 'ss' '11' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 ['7' '19 'ss' '1' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
```

Comment: It should work, since executing `update tablename set fieldname = rowid` works in SQLite. Did you start with a list of 1..14 ? The rowids do not change if you delete a row. Try executing `vacuum`, then your update.

Comment: You don't; if you need a row number, you calculate it on the fly with `row_number()` or a related window function, or in the code that's doing something with the result of the query. A sqlite rowid is **not** a row number and shouldn't be treated like one. It's just a unique indentifier.

Comment: Even the concept of a row number doesn't make sense without something to order the rows by; sql tables are conceptually unordered sets.

Comment: I dont know how to do this. I want it to look like this

` [**'1'** '19' '11' '11' 'Комплекс 1300 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 [**'2'** '191' 'nn' '11' 'Комплекс 1300 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 [**'3'** '19' 'ss' '11' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 [**'4'** '19' 'ss' '1' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 [**'5**' '191' 'mm' '11' 'Комплекс 1300 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 [**'6'** '19' 'ss' '11' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']
 [**'7'** '19 'ss' '1' 'Стрижка 1100 RUB' '17:00' '15 апреля']`